# How to store the JSON request in a variable using preprocessor and those variable should pass it to subsequent request as base64 value in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

My requirement is i need to store the whole Json request in a single variable(using preprocessor) and pass those variable name in request to get the expected response.

Step 1 : I created a JSR223 Preprocessor test element and placed the Json body. Using CSV config element, i am passing different values to this Json body request at every iteration.

[JSR223 request image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H94SP.jpg)

Step 2: In http request, i am passing that variable name(ex :foo) as in a base64 function to convert that whole Json request as base64 value to get the expected response.[Http request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLvsY.jpg).

Could please someone explain how to achieve this scenario here. Please refer the attached screenshot for reference.

Answer (score 0):

1. `i am passing different values to this Json body request at every iteration` - no, you don't, as per [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) documentation:

   > Or Use Script Text and check Cache compiled script if available property.
   >
   > When using this feature, ensure your script code does not use JMeter variables or JMeter function calls directly in script code as **caching would only cache first replacement**. Instead use script parameters.
2. You cannot have "plain" JSON in JSR223 test elements, it will cause compilation failure, you need to convert it into a [String](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#all-strings) first. Assuming point 1 you need to use [`vars` shorthand for JMeterVariables class instance](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) to read `p_loanamount` and other values and to store the JSON into `foo` JMeter Variable, so it would be something like:

   ```
   def payload = """{
         "value": """ + vars.get('p_loanamount') + """,
         "type": "string",
         "key": "consumer_load_calculator.loan_amount",
         "stepTitle": "Loan Information",
         "formattedValue": "€ 4,000",
         "label": "LOAN AMOUNT"
       }"""
   vars.put('foo', payload)
   ```
3. The same applies to your [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) which should look like:

   ```
   ${__groovy(vars.get('foo').bytes.encodeBase64().toString(),)}
   ```
4. [Don't post code as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2897748)

Comment: Hi Dmitri,
Thanks for your response. i am able to store the JSON in foo variable.
I am facing issue with Step 2: "${__groovy('${foo}'.bytes.encodeBase64().toString(),)}". i passed my request like this but it's not converting to Base64  and request going as empty. i tried like this also "${__groovy('foo'.bytes.encodeBase64().toString(),)}"
Could you please help here.